# Image does not be shown

Tags: assets, image, navigation

Good mornig

I am having a problem with my bannerImage.
First off i show you how i did it and what the problem is.

[image]

In the first picture you can see, how i get the image.
This method works fine for 3 other pages on this website.¨
My field setup is correct, because in other templates it works fine.

The only thing i can now think off is that there's something wrong with the name of the template.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**
I fixed this problem like this.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might be a silly question, but is your `.pic-banner` class for this template styled correctly, ie. given a height etc?

Since you're setting it is a background-image it won't "expand" the element to the aspects of the image as it normally would using a img-element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes if there is a link to the image in the url, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think that the second screen has anything todo with it, because it's just about titles and adding a class to the body.
2. What do you get in the source of the rendered page? Does the div inside the if statement appear or not? And if yes, try to open the image url, which is created, in a new tab and see what you get.